# Metrics for implicit data in the recommender system with NCF

Tags: neural-networks, python, recommender-system, metric

Which metrics for analysis and evaluation for implicit data in a recommender system do you use? And which ones do you use when you are looking for the closest neighbors to make a recommendation?

I'm using the NCF model.

[image]

The architecture of a Neural Collaborative Filtering model. Taken from the [Neural Collaborative Filtering paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.05031).

First I let the model train with the help of the NCF model. Then I find the closest neighbors with k-means.

I found metrics like MSE, RMSE, Precision, Recall, ... and [What metric should I use for assessing Implicit matrix factorization recommender with ALS?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226825/what-metric-should-i-use-for-assessing-implicit-matrix-factorization-recommender) .
I'm not sure which ones are best and how I can then determine whether the closest neighbors are good or bad.

- What metrics are there to evaluate the model?
- What metrics are there to evaluate whether the neighbors found are "good"?